# Android get ImageView actual height and width dynamically

Tags: android, android-imageview

EDIT:

My new question is how can I dynamically get the actual ImageView width and height if it's set to fill_parent ? I mean method without error or large memory consumption.

Comment: You need to read about handling images on android
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: I have read a lot but this is the problem I haven't encountered yet

Comment: @Traabefi The code looks fine. Are images not loading at all or they are slow loading? Title of your question and content are contradict each other. Size of heap depends on many reasons: images size, free memory and many others.

Comment: Are you enclosing a linearlayout inside the imageview?

Comment: Well, now I found where was the problem and what caused error. The line with imageview.getMaxWidth() was consuming too much memory and when I set that to some fix value it worked almost instantly

Comment: I am going to edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new   ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

            int height = imageView.getHeight();
            int width = imageView.getWidth();

            return false;
        }
    });
```